# Unrecognized selector sent to instance Custom Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make a Custom Cell for my UITableView.

So, I create  a class (`UITableViewCell`) and I named HomeCell. This class has a xib file with label named titleCell.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I wrote:

```
HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id oneObject in xib){
            if([oneObject isKindOfClass:[HomeCell class]]){
                cell = (HomeCell *) oneObject;
            }
        }
    }

    //Get object at index data
    HomeObjectCell *tempObject = [self.dataForCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Title : %@",tempObject.title); // The tempObject.title return a NSString example

    cell.titleCell.text = tempObject.title; // <-- ERROR !
```

When I run the application, I got:

> [UITableViewCell titleCell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e61890

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Are you absolutely sure that:**

1) **.. your class "HomeCell" is named correct for the table cell?** Select the cell, select 'identity inspector' -> section 'Custom Class' and take a look

2) **.. referencing outlets with connections to each label/ui image is made?** Try select your cell again, select 'Connections inspector' and take a look

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I solved my problem, i deleted my class and i create a new UITableViewCell...But i think that i had a naming conflict..

Comment: That's also an approach to make sure of things is right. Feel free to upvote my answer and close this case:)

Answer (score 0):

In the description you mentioned that HomeCell has member named titleLable.

In the code you have used cell.titleCell.text.

So, I think you should use cell.titleLabel.text instead of cell.titleCell. The crash message is also suggesting same thing that there is no proprty with cell.titleCell exists in HomeCell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a tape mistake, i have a titleCell and not a titleLabel ! I edited the description...

My HomeCell.h look like this : `@interface HomeCell : UITableViewCell @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageCell; @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleCell; @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionCell; @end`

Comment: Check.. Have you synthesize titleCell property in your HomeCell.m file.

Comment: Yes ! `@synthesize imageCell;
@synthesize titleCell;
@synthesize descriptionCell;`

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the file owner in the xib file is of Class HomeCell.